# xor conditional in bash

Tags: bash, xor

I want to see if any of two variables are set, but not both in bash.

I have something like this, but I am not sure about the syntax. I know xor operator does are not logical and should be use as bitwise, but how can i parse [ -z "$tag" ]  into 1 or 0 instead of true or false

```sh
if [ -z "$tag" ] ^ [ -z "$flag" ]; then
  echo yes
else 
  echo no
fi
```

Comment: There is no `^` operator in bash.

Comment: @melpomene: Sure there is. It's a bitwise exclusive or (but you're right in that there's no _logical_ exclusive or).

Answer (score 8):

```
! testA; TESTA=$?
! testB; TESTB=$?

if [ $TESTA -ne $TESTB ]; then
    echo 'Exactly one of testA or testB was true -- the other was not'
fi
```

The `testA` and `testB` can be arbitrary programs/pipelines such as `[ -z "$tag" ]` or `[ -z "$flag" ]`. The important part is to inverse the return code with `!` prefix in order to turn `0` into `1` and `1-255` into `0`, in order to reduce the set of possible exit codes to a binary `0` or `1`. And then you can safely check if both are different `[ … -ne … ]`.

Comment: I like this one! It's generalized and concise! (and portable)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Simple and easy to write.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing I could come up with:

```
if [ "${tag:+A}" != "${flag:+A}" ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

`"${foo:+bar}"` expands to `bar` if `foo` is non-empty, and the empty string otherwise.

`"${tag:+A}"` normalizes the value of `$tag`: If it is empty, it remains empty; if it is non-empty, it turns into `A`.

`xor` is simply non-equality on booleans. Here we use non-equality on normalized strings instead, which is provided by the `!=` operator of `[`.

---

For a general solution with two arbitrary commands `foo` and `bar` (not just is-string-empty tests), you could use the following:

```
if if foo; then ! bar; else bar; fi; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

It looks a bit awful and you need to repeat `bar` twice, but I can't think of a more concise way to express it.

You could run both commands beforehand and save their exit statuses in variables, which would remove the `bar` repetition, but would make the code longer overall.

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant solution I have found

```
[[ "${VAR1:+true}" == "${VAR2:+true}" ]]
```

will return 0 if both exist or both are null/unset.
will return 1 if only one exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `melpomene` answer, I've found a way to generalize this logic for any number of variables
Example if you want to check `$varA xor $varB xor $varC`
You can do the following :

```
SIMULATE_XOR="${varA:+A}${varB:+A}${varC:+A}"
if [[ "${SIMULATE_XOR}" != "A" ]]; then 
    echo "you must set one, and only one variable"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by **melpomene**'s solution, I put his crucial `if` statement in a function, but to use this function with quoted arguments, we need `eval` for the shell to perform all expansions that are necessary on the positional parameters *before* executing the statement:

`function xor { eval "if $1; then ! $2; else $2; fi"; }`

This way, we may pass arbitrary commands, e. g. `xor '[ -z "$PATH" ]' "find ~ -maxdepth 1 -name '.bash*'"`

**Edit:**

This function narrows the commands to `[[ <unary test op> <operand> ]]` tests but accepts an arbitrary number of operands:

```
function exactlyOne # Args: <unary test op> operands...
{
    local operator=$1; shift

    local operand1 operand2

    if (($# == 2)); then
        operand1=$1
        operand2=$2
        shift 2

        if eval [[ $operator \$operand1 ]]; then ! eval [[ $operator \$operand2 ]]; else eval [[ $operator \$operand2 ]]; fi
    else # Recurse
        operand1=$1; shift

        if eval [[ $operator \$operand1 ]]; then ! exactlyOne $operator "$@"; else exactlyOne $operator "$@"; fi
    fi
}
```

To test e. g. if exactly one variable has a value assigned, just write
`exactlyOne -n "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" ...`.

Comment: Might as well use `\$operator` in your `evals` to prevent shell splitting the variable contents on whitespace. More secure that way.

Answer (score 0):

The following one seem to work with any number of arguments (and if they are quoted or not)

```
function excl_or() {
    local -i cnt=0
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        [[ -n $1 ]] && let cnt++
        shift
    done
    [[ $(( $cnt % 2)) -eq 1 ]] 
}
```

Or the same with the string replacement as mentioned before

```
function excl_or_2() {
    local tmp=""
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        tmp+=${1:+E}
        shift
    done
    [[ $(( ${#tmp} % 2 )) -eq 1 ]]
}
```

Note: some answers here with more than 2 arguments are not working since

```
True XOR True XOR True = False XOR True = True
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer the original question, I think this simple solution will do the job:

> ```
> exclusive_or() {
>     [[ -n "$1" && -z "$2" ]]
> }
> if exclusive_or "$tag" "$flag"; then
>     echo yes
> else
>     echo no
> fi
> ```

because if "tag" is unset and "flag" is set, the first argument in the function will be set to $flag.

Comment: This is wrong, because if `$tag` is unset, the first argument to the `exclusive_or` function  will be the empty string `""`, and the second argument will be whatever `$flag` is set to. It would work when not quoting the arguments to the function, but that would run the risk of word splitting when the first argument contains whitespace, making the function ignore the intended second argument and always exiting non-zero i.e. false.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using that function with arguments unquoted.